# How to manage loading animation thread? - C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, visual-studio

I am trying to do a loading form. So that I've put an animated gif to do the loading effect.

What happens is that when I use the `loading.Visible = true` property this is not visible until the click event ends.

Here is the code.

```
Private void btnLogin_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     loading.Visible = true;
     if (ConnectDataBase())
     {
         OpenForm2();
         This.Close();
     }
     else MessageBox.Show ("User or password, incorrect");
     loading.Visible = false;
}
```

The Data Base takes 3 to 6 seconds to respond in the `ConnectDataBase()` function, but the gif does not become visible until the event ends.

Someone could tell me, how could I do this?

Comment: `this.Refresh();`

Comment: Now, the gif image appears but is not animating.

Comment: You have blocked the UI thread, that's normal. If you want to keep the UI responsive use async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to run the database connection in the background. There are many ways of doing this but with the advent of `async/await`, this would be the easiest way:

```
private async void btnLogin_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     loading.Visible = true;
     if (await Task.Run(() => ConnectDataBase()))
     {
         OpenForm2();
         This.Close();
     }
     else MessageBox.Show ("User or password, incorrect");
     loading.Visible = false;
}
```

Note the following changes:

- I made the method `async void` to signal to the compiler that we want to use `async/await`
- I created a task to run the database connection:

  ```
  await Task.Run(() => ConnectDataBase())
  ```

  This will return a `bool`, the result of `ConnectDataBase()` and will
  essentially do the same thing as the other answer here, just with
  less manual clutter and handling of tasks.

**Observe**: With background execution like this it is possible for the user to click on the `Login` button again, while the first click is still executing (and trying to connect to the database). You should take steps to ensure this is not possible, like disabling the login button (and other fields, such as username, password, etc.) while this is executing, something like:

```
private async void btnLogin_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     btnLogin.Enabled = eUsername.Enabled = ePassword.Enabled = false;
     loading.Visible = true;
     ... rest of method
     loading.Visible = false;
     btnLogin.Enabled = eUsername.Enabled = ePassword.Enabled = true;
}
```

---

**Note** It would also be better, if possible, to rewrite the `ConnectDataBase` method to be async in nature as most .NET database connection services nowadays have methods to do this. Without knowing more about what this method does I can only make a general comment.

Here's an example of how to write a SQL Server connection attempt:

```
public static async Task<bool> ConnectDataBase()
{
    var connection = new SqlConnection("connection string");
    try
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        // store "connection" somewhere I assume?
        return true;
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        connection.Dispose();
        return false;
    }
}
```

With this change you would change your `if`-statement in your original method to this:

```
     if (await ConnectDataBase())
```

Comment: Thanks @Lasser. This is the best way. +1

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work you need to invoke ConnectDataBase() on a different thread.  One way to do this is:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loading.Visible = true;
    Task.Run<bool>(() =>
        {
            return ConnectDataBase();
        })
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.Result)
            {
                OpenForm2();
                this.Close();
            }
            else MessageBox.Show("User or password, incorrect");
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Comment: Thanks men. You help me a lot.

Comment: Or use `async/await` if this is available in the given Visual Studio/C#/.NET version.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen what is the easiest `Task` or  `async/await`? could you post an answer using `async/await`?